# Solving a problem of a particle in harminic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Im trying to solve the following problem:

> A particle is in the ground state $ \psi\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{2m\omega}{\pi\hbar}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}e^{-\frac{m\omega x^{2}}{\hbar}} $ of a harmonic oscillator potential. Suddenly the potential is removed without affecting the particle's state. Find the probability density function $ f\left(p\right) $ of the particle's momentum after the potential has been removed.

Now I know that $ p=\hbar k $, and therefore I thought it would be better to use Fourier transform in order to find the wave function in the $k $ space.

This is the result of the transform that I found:

$$ \tilde{\psi}\left(k\right)=\left(\frac{2\pi\hbar}{m\omega}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}e^{-\frac{\hbar k^{2}}{4m\omega}} $$

But how can I use the function that I found in the $k $ space in order to find the PDF of the momentum?

I tried to make it look a little bit more comfortable by:

$$ \tilde{\psi}\left(k\right)=\left(\frac{2\pi\hbar}{m\omega}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}e^{-\frac{\hbar k^{2}}{4m\omega}}=\left(\frac{2\pi\hbar}{m\omega}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}e^{-\frac{p^{2}}{4m\omega\hbar}} $$

Assume I want to find the function in the bases of $p $, given that I have the function in the basis of $ k$; the function that I found is

$$ \tilde{\psi}\left(k\right)=\left(\frac{2\pi\hbar}{m\omega}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}e^{-\frac{\hbar k^{2}}{4m\omega}} $$

What would be the right way to move to the $p $ base?

Would it be just option 1 :

$$ \tilde{\psi}\left(k\right)=\left(\frac{2\pi\hbar}{m\omega}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}e^{-\frac{\hbar k^{2}}{4m\omega}}=\left(\frac{2\pi\hbar}{m\omega}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}e^{-\frac{\hbar^{2}k^{2}}{4m\omega\hbar}}=\left(\frac{2\pi\hbar}{m\omega}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}e^{-\frac{p^{2}}{4m\omega}}\Rightarrow\tilde{\psi}\left(p\right)=\left(\frac{2\pi\hbar}{m\omega}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}e^{-\frac{p^{2}}{4m\omega}} $$

(And then multiply by a constant to normalize)

Or rather option 2:

$$ \tilde{\psi}\left(k\right)=\left(\frac{2\pi\hbar}{m\omega}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}e^{-\frac{\hbar k^{2}}{4m\omega}}\Rightarrow\tilde{\psi}\left(p\right)=\tilde{\psi}\left(\hbar k\right)=\left(\frac{2\pi\hbar}{m\omega}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}e^{-\frac{\hbar\left(\hbar k\right)^{2}}{4m\omega}}=\left(\frac{2\pi\hbar}{m\omega}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}e^{-\frac{\hbar p^{2}}{4m\omega}} $$

(And then multiply by a constant to normalie the function)

Comment: Are you familiar with $|\tilde\psi|^2$?

Comment: @BioPhysicist This would not give the right answer.\

Comment: Well you have found the initial state. Did you then go onto finding how $\tilde\psi$ evolves over time?

Comment: @BioPhysicist The right answer should be $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar m\omega}}e^{-\frac{p^{2}}{2m\omega\hbar}} $ which is basicly $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}} $ times the function that I found from the transform, I guess it follows from the normalization conditions but Im looking for an explanation for this (because Im not really familier with the fourier transform). This is how we defined the transform in calss: $ \tilde{\psi}\left(k\right)=\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi\left(x\right)e^{ikx}dx $

Comment: Ah ok. Yeah, just normalize. It looks like that Fourier Transform version just doesn't preserve normalization. The difference is just multiplying by a constant.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I see. I edit the question with another clarification that I need. Can you tell which of the ways that I wrote is the right way to write the wave function in the bases of $ p $ ? (given that I already done the transform to $k $ space)

Comment: Also what is the meaning of the given detail "suddenly the potential is removed" what wluld happen if the potential would remain the same?

Comment: [Due diligence first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet#Gaussian_wave_packets_in_quantum_mechanics).

Comment: The second option doesn't make sense, so the quantity in the exponent has dimensionality $[\hbar^2]$, but it has to be dimensionless.
"Suddenly" means that the wavefunction doesn't have time to change during potential removal. If the potential remains the same, the state just acquire phase $e^{-i\omega t}$ (note, that the given function doesn't correspond to [the conventional one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Hamiltonian_and_energy_eigenstates), so its frequency $\omega$ is half the size of the real frequency in the harmonic oscillator hamiltonian)